# Mult-output files with Makefile

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, makefile, automation, cuda

I am a cuda programmer and new in vscode and Makefile environment.
For a better programming, I use multiple .cu files for my functions. Thus, for the pull_model and build_meshgrid functions, the makefile becomes:

```
# Target rules
all: build

build: kernel

check.deps:
ifeq ($(SAMPLE_ENABLED),0)
    @echo "Launch file will be waived due to the above missing dependencies"
else
    @echo "Launch file is ready - all dependencies have been met"
endif

kernel: kernel.o Engine/Engine.o Engine/pull_model.o Engine/build_meshgrid.o
    $(EXEC) $(NVCC) $(ALL_LDFLAGS) $(GENCODE_FLAGS) -o $@ $+ $(LIBRARIES)
    $(EXEC) mkdir -p bin/$(TARGET_ARCH)/$(TARGET_OS)/$(BUILD_TYPE)
    $(EXEC) cp $@ bin/$(TARGET_ARCH)/$(TARGET_OS)/$(BUILD_TYPE)

%.o: %.cu
    $(EXEC) $(NVCC) $(INCLUDES) $(ALL_CCFLAGS) $(GENCODE_FLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
    
run: build
    $(EXEC) ./kernel

testrun: build

clean:
    rm -f kernel *.o Engine/*.o
    rm -rf bin/$(TARGET_ARCH)/$(TARGET_OS)/$(BUILD_TYPE)/kernel

clobber: clean
```

**I need to reduce the kernel somehow, like this:**

```
kernel: kernel.o Engine/*.o
    $(EXEC) $(NVCC) $(ALL_LDFLAGS) $(GENCODE_FLAGS) -o $@ $+ $(LIBRARIES)
    $(EXEC) mkdir -p bin/$(TARGET_ARCH)/$(TARGET_OS)/$(BUILD_TYPE)
    $(EXEC) cp $@ bin/$(TARGET_ARCH)/$(TARGET_OS)/$(BUILD_TYPE)
```

**So, all .cu files under Engine folder are targed.**

Best Regards!

Comment: Please do not embed images in SO questions, and definitely do not use links to other sites holding images.  Images can't be cut/pasted, they are hard for people with some kinds of vision issues to look at, and links to other sites disappear.  Just cut and paste the relevant text (with proper formatting) into your question.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I remade my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can't use `Engine/*.o` because when you run your makefile, no object files exist and so this wildcard will expand to nothing, then nothing will be built (except `kernel.o`).

It's a catch-22 because you can't just tell make "build all the object files that you would build if you knew which objects to build!"

If what you want is to build object files for all source files in the `Engine` directory, you can tell make to do *that*:

```
SRCS := $(wildcard Engine/*.c)
OBJS := $(SRCS:%.c=%.o)

kernel: kernel.o $(OBJS)
         ....
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!

I just changed the .c to .cu